# Retrieve all the Document Library with folder and file count using SharePoint Client Object Model

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, console-application

Hi Friends i have a SharePoint site having more Document Library's i just want to display this as a Console application using SharePoint Client Object Model.

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to display its items?

Comment: Yes i want to display it's items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fetch all the files from a folder and do a Count() as stated in the accepted solution above. This will load a lot of (overhead) information you don't need. And with large libraries or folders 'Threshold exceeded' exceptions will be thrown.

Use the ItemCount property of the document library or the folders.

```
 foreach (var list in docLibs)
   {             
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
        context.Load(list.ItemCount);
        context.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        
        Console.WriteLine("---- library item count " + list.ItemCount);
        
        // this loop below can be simplified with one linq query. 
        // Kept it for simplicity reasons.
        foreach (Folder folder in list.RootFolder.Folders)
        {
          context.Load(folder, p=> p.ItemCount);
          context.ExecuteQuery();
          Console.WriteLine(folder.Name + "---- File count " + folder.ItemCount);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

Following is the code to retrieve all document libraries with folders and file count.Hope it helps.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter your user name (format: username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com)");
string userName = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter your password.");
SecureString password = GetPasswordFromConsoleInput();
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("Site Url"))
{
   context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName,password);
   Web web = context.Web;       
   var docLibs = context.LoadQuery(web.Lists.Where(l => l.BaseTemplate == 101));
   context.ExecuteQuery();

   foreach (var list in docLibs)
   {             
        Console.WriteLine(list.Title);
        context.Load(list.RootFolder.Folders);
        context.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (Folder folder in list.RootFolder.Folders)
        {
          context.Load(folder.Files);
          context.ExecuteQuery();
          Console.WriteLine(folder.Name + "---- File count " + folder.Files.Count);
        }

     }
           Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: getting error at the place **context.ExecuteQuery()**   it displays _An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll_

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: have you provided credential?

Comment: yes able to connect the folder and all

Comment: With this code you will run into 'threshold exceeded' errors when you have a library with a large amount of documents.

Answer (score 2):

It will return you all document library data in application.

```
 using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("Your Site URL "))
                {
                    List docList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document Library Name");
                    clientContext.Load(docList); CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>";
                    ListItemCollection listItems = docList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                    clientContext.Load(listItems);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    foreach (ListItem listItem in listItems)
                    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} ", listItem.Id);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Here am getting only the the id just like this

Comment: Id 1 id2 ...... id 15 i want the folder name and it's file count can u help me